# grunt task copy failing to write the file in the destination

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-copy, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm new to gruntjs and struggling to understand why a simple copy file task is not working. Below is my code in Gruntfile.js.

```js
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    "use strict";

    // Project configuration
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON("package.json"),

        // copy other css files
        copy: {
            dist: {
                files: {
                    //expand: true, // required when using cwd
                    //cwd: ['.'], // set working folder / root to copy
                    src: './wwwroot/lib/html5-reset/assets/css/reset.css', // copy all files and subfolders
                    dest: './wwwroot/css/' // destination folder
                }
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-copy");

    grunt.registerTask("copyCss", ["copy"]);
};
```

When I execute the task I'm getting the following error

> Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...OK
>   + copyCss
>   Running tasks: copy
>   Running "copy" task
>   Running "copy:dist" (copy) task
>   Verifying property copy.dist exists in config...OK
>   Files: ./wwwroot/lib/html5-reset/assets/css/reset.css -> src
>   Files: ./wwwroot/css/ -> dest
>   Options: encoding="utf8", processContent=false, processContentExclude=[], timestamp=false, mode=false
>   Copying ./wwwroot/lib/html5-reset/assets/css/reset.css -> src
>   Reading ./wwwroot/lib/html5-reset/assets/css/reset.css...OK
>   Writing src...ERROR
>   Warning: Unable to write "src" file (Error code: EISDIR). Used --force, continuing.
>   Done, but with warnings.
>   Process terminated with code 0.

Appreciated your help in pinpointing the issue.

Comment: What are you trying to copy? Are you wanting to copy the file named `reset.css` _from_ the `wwwroot/lib/html5-reset/assets/css/` directory _to_ the `./wwwroot/css/` directory? Or something else?

Comment: Yes, I’m trying copy the html5-reset css file from lib folder to css folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nodejs error [`EISDIR`](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors) is described as:

> `EISDIR` (Is a directory): An operation expected a file, but the given pathname was a directory.

Configure your `Gruntfile.js` as shown below instead.

**Gruntfile.js**

```js
module.exports = function (grunt) {
  "use strict";

  // Project configuration
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON("package.json"),

    copy: {
      dist: {
        expand: true,
        cwd: 'wwwroot/lib/html5-reset/assets/css',
        src: 'reset.css',
        dest: 'wwwroot/css'
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-copy");
  grunt.registerTask("copyCss", ["copy"]);
};
```

---

Running the following command:

```
grunt copyCss
```

will copy the file named `reset.css` from the `wwwroot/lib/html5-reset/assets/css/` directory to the `wwwroot/css/` directory.

**Example Before:**

```
.
├── Gruntfile.js
├── node_modules
│   └── ...
├── package.json
└── wwwroot
    └── lib
        └── html5-reset
            └── assets
                └── css
                    └── reset.css   <--------------
```

**Example After:**

```
.
├── Gruntfile.js
├── node_modules
│   └── ...
├── package.json
└── wwwroot
    ├── css
    │   └── reset.css               <--------------
    └── lib
        └── html5-reset
            └── assets
                └── css
                    └── reset.css   <--------------
```

---

#### Edit: Creating a custom task instead of using *grunt-contrib-copy*

If you are only wanting to copy one file then using `grunt-contrib-copy` seems somewhat unnecessary. Consider creating a [custom Task](https://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks#custom-tasks) instead. For instance:

**Gruntfile.js**

```js
module.exports = function (grunt) {
  "use strict";

  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON("package.json")
  });

  grunt.registerTask('copyCss', 'Copies a single file', function() {
    grunt.file.copy(
      'wwwroot/lib/html5-reset/assets/css/reset.css',
      'wwwroot/css/reset.css'
    )
  });

};
```

- The aforementioned custom task utilizes grunt's build-in [`grunt.file.copy`](https://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.file#grunt.file.copy) method.
- You may also want to consider adding some error handling to that custom Task too. For instance, you may want to utilize grunt's built-in [`grunt.file.exists`](https://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.file#grunt.file.exists) method to check whether the `reset.css` file exists before proceeding to copy it.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation @RobC. Appreciated your help in understanding the root cause of the issue as well as the custom task snippet. I tried both ways and both are working fine as you explained.